# lapply with different indices in list of lists

Tags: r, list, loops, nested, lapply

I'm trying to get the output of a certain column (`$new_age = numeric values`) within lists of lists.

Data is "my_groups", which consists of 28 lists. Those lists have lists themselves of irregular size:

> 92 105  96  86  91  94  73 100  87  89  88  90 112  82  95  83  94 106
> 91 101  86  81  89  68  89  87 109  73 (len_df)

The 1st list has 92 lists, the 2nd 105 etc. ... until the 28th list with 73 lists.

First, I want my function to iterate through the 28 years of data and second, within these years I want to iterate through `len_df`, since `$new_age` is in the nested lists.

What I tried is this:

```
test <- lapply(seq(1:28), function(i) sapply(seq(1:len_df), function(j) (my_groups[[i]][[j]]$new_age) ) )
```

However, the index is out of bounds and I'm not sure how to combine two different indices for the nested lists. Unlist is not ideal, since I have to treat the data as separate groups and sorted for each year.

Expected output: `$new_age` (numeric values) for each of the 28 years e.g. 1st = 92 values, 2nd = 105 values etc.

Any idea how to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: edited the post.

Comment: `seq(1:28)` is nonsensical. Either use `seq` *or* use the `:` operator, don’t use both. Furthermore, `1 : len_df` is error-prone and should *always* be replaced by `seq_len(len_df)` (or `seq_along(…)`) since `1 : …` does the wrong thing for empty vectors.

Comment: A reproducible example means a cut down example such that anyone else can copy the data from the question and paste it into their R session.  I have provided one in the Note at the end of my answer for you this time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for this important advice! I replaced the seq(1:len_df) with seq_along(len_df), since seq_len(len_df) does not work in this case. Also, lapply loops only until the maximum of what's put in at first. When using the indices i and j the output is always 28 lists and 28 values, but not 28 lists and 92, 105 values etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different approaches:

**1) whole object approach** Assuming that the input is `L` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and that what is wanted is a list of `length(L)` numeric vectors, i.e. `list(1:2, 3:5)`, consisting of the `new_age` values:

```
lapply(L, sapply, `[[`, "new_age")
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5
```

**2) indices** If you want to do it using indices, as in the code shown in question, then using `seq_along`:

```
ix <- seq_along(L)
lapply(ix, function(i) sapply(seq_along(L[[i]]), function(j) L[[i]][[j]]$new_age))
```

**3) unlist**  To use unlist form an appropriate grouping variable using `rep` and split into separate vectors by it.  This assumes that new_age are the only leaves which may or may not be the case in your data but is the case in the reproducible example in the Note at the end.

```
split(unname(unlist(L)), rep(seq_along(L), lengths(L)))
```

### Note

```
L <- list(list(list(new_age = 1), list(new_age = 2)),
  list(list(new_age = 3), list(new_age = 4), list(new_age = 5)))
```

Comment: Thanks for showing different approaches! Much appreciated. I noticed that the first and second one work just as expeceted. However, when computing e.g. the mean, or max etc. afterwards I'm getting NAN's. Putting "mean" directly in front of the second function in the 2nd method works however. As for the third approach, R says "data length is not a multiple of split variable".

Comment: If Lout is the output from any of the three alternatives in the answer then sapply(Lout, mean) gives the corresponding means.  If there are NA's in the data sapply(Lout, mean, na.rm = TRUE) will exclude them.   If that is not what you need you will have to provide a reproducible example since we don't know what you have as you haven't provided such an example.  Also did you read the caveat on the third alternative?